# Why is my mongoose document property not properly setting to another _id property

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to set up a simple mongoose test file, and am getting some pretty confusing results. When I run this following code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema; 
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp');

var personSchema = Schema({
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});
var storySchema = Schema({
  creator : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String,
  fans     : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
});
var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

var aaron = new Person({name: 'Aaron', age: 100 });

aaron.save(function (err) {
  if (err) console.log("something didnt work!");

  var story1 = new Story({
    title: "Once upon a timex.",
    creator: aaron._id  // assign the _id from the person to creator
  });
  console.log(aaron._id);
  story1.save();
});
Story.findOne({ title: 'Once upon a timex.' },function(err,story){
  console.log(story); // printing here
});
```

I get this output:

```
{
  _id: 54b9e08ed983b41d432473e4,
  title: 'Once upon a timex.',
  _creator: 0,
  __v: 0,
  fans: [] 
}
54bcacb4c812ec812382b6b2
```

there are many things that don't really make sense in this. As you can see from my code I only console.log(); 2 things:

- arron._id
- the story document created in the save callback of aaron

Question 1:
When we print out the story object, we see that the creator field is set to 0 (we'll get to this later), and underscore has been added for some reason (I assume it's because it links to an ObjectId). I also tried to add an underscore to creator, like it showed in the documentation, and this caused the creator property to simply not get saved to the document. Could anybody explain how _ interacts with mongoose?

Question 2:
When we try to set creator:aaron_id it gets set to 0, we know that arron._id is not 0, because we print it successfully in the same scope. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: The issue is that that the find query executes before your save query does (remember that they execute asynchronously).

Try:

```
var aaron = new Person({name: 'Aaron', age: 100 });

aaron.save(function (err) {
  if (err) console.log("something didnt work!");

  var story1 = new Story({
    title: "Once upon a timex.",
    creator: aaron._id  // assign the _id from the person to creator
  });
  console.log(aaron._id);
  story1.save(function(err){
    Story.findOne({ title: 'Once upon a timex.' },function(err,story){
       console.log(story); // printing here
    });
  });
});
```

Question 2: Are you sure you're not looking up older objects that you attempted to save? I have a feeling that at some point story had the property _creator and you changed it to 'creator', but its finding your older document because you are not querying by id. Try changing your story query to:

```
Story.findOne({ title: 'Once upon a timex.', creator: aaron._id },function(err,story){
  console.log(story); // printing here
});
```